# How to get my application to work on appengine

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

I developed a web application the usual way and hosted on a normal shared server.

These are what I mean by usual

- Include my PHP function files (using php include/require)
- Use my normal MySQL database with msqli
- Upload my files normally to the server using FTP.

For some reasons, I need to move the web app to appengine, I have succeeded in uploading the files but it shows me this error:

```
500 Server Error
```

with this error in my log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named index
```

What changes do I need to make to my files to enable my website work well on appengine without issues?

EDIT (Content of app.yaml)

```
application: gcdc2013-myworkset
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: index.php

- url: /css
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

I tried changing runtime to php but it gave an error which cleared immediately i changed it back to python27

**EDIT:**

Updated `app.yaml` file (Project deploys now but shows this error for all PHP files: `Could not guess mimetype for excel/excel_reader.php.  Using application/octet-stream.`
 Also the project appears as blank when viewed on the browser):

```
application: gcdc2013-myworkset
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: index.php

- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /index\.php
  script: index.php

- url: /features
  script: features/index.php

- url: /about
  script: about/index.php

- url: /oauth2callback/?
  script: signup.php  

- url: (.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)
  static_files: $1.$2
  upload: (.*).(.*)

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js
```

Also, how can I import mysql database that I exported from my localhost to the appengine?

Comment: It looks like you have your app configured for the python runtime, instead of php. Could you post the contents of your app.yaml file?

Comment: @IanGSY Kindly check my post, I edited and added the content of my app.yaml

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
runtime: python27
```

To:

```
runtime: php
```

And remove:

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much. It deploys now but shows me a blank page. Also shows this errors during deploy process: 
Could not guess mimetype for excel/excel_reader.php.  Using application/octet-stream. I've added the current app.yaml content in the last edit.